# .Net IBM MQ Client configuraton to have multiple hosts (and reconnection ability)

Tags: .net-6.0, ibm-mq

I am trying to configure my IBM MQ client to have multiple (possible) hosts with the ability to reconnect if one is unavailable.

A code snippet (using .net6 and ibm-mq-client v9.2.0)

```
        Hashtable properties = new()
        {
            { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
            { MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "192.168.1.10(1104),192.168.1.11(1104)" },
            { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "MyChannel" },
            { MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT }
        };

        MQQueueManager manager = new("MyManager", properties);
```

Attempting to connect using this results in an error with code `2538` (host unavailable?)

The same setup works if I only specific one single host in the connection name

Can someone point out what I'm dong wrong?

Comment: When using single conname - which conname worked - 192.168.1.10(1104) or 192.168.1.11(1104)?  Have you also checked if listener is running?

Comment: @Shashi the IPs are of course fictional in the example, but if I specific the current (online) host on it's own it works.  If I supply it as in the example above it does not